# Unclear about how binding works in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I have this child component in the template of my own component:

```
<template>
    ...
    <ChildComponent
        :model-value="getFruitType(selectedFruit)"
        @update:model-value="onSelectFruit"
    >
    ...
</template>
```

My `selectedFruit` variable is reactive:

```
const selectedFruit = ref({});
```

My `getFruitType` function looks like this:

```
const getFruitType = (selectedFruit) => { return { fruitName: selectedFruit.name } }
```

Now somehow whenever `selectedFruit` changes, Vue automatically calls `getFruitType()` on the `:model-value` binding again, and `<ChildComponent>` gets an updated `model-value` prop. How is this happening?!

Does Vue look at the entire expression, `getFruitType(selectedFruit)`, sees that a `selectedFruit` is part of it and that it's reactive, and just knows to evaluate the entire expression based off of that?

Shouldn't this only happen if `getFruitType` was a computed property?

Comment: getFruitType is called on every template update, its calls aren't tied to selectedFruit changes. It's less efficient than a computed, especially since it returns a new object on every call

Comment: @EstusFlask, so the inclusion of selectedFruit within the v-bind expression itself does not trigger a template update on its own. Instead something else triggers an update, and when that happens, getFruitType gets called as well. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's it.